# How can i print a new line in a text file, each time i press a button?

Tags: c#, oop

I coded a button to add input as a string to a text file , but i want to add a string to the file each time the button is being press, as it is rigth now my program overwrites the old string in the file.

Code for button :

```
 private void BtnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = txtUsername.Text;
            password = txtPassword.Text;


            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(username + ' ' + password);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Hint: you could look at the overloads for `StreamWriter` - or more simply, just use `File.AppendAllText(path, $"{username} {password}");`

Comment: use `File.AppendAllText(path, $"{username} {password}{Environment.NewLine}");` this will append the text in a new line on each click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this overload of the StreamWriter constructor.

```
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, append: true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(username + ' ' + password);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[As msdn says about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-6.0) `File.AppendAllText`:

> Appends the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does
> not already exist.

So as an alternative you can use `File.AppendAllText`:

```
File.AppendAllText("yourFile.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Or if you want to have a newline

```
File.AppendAllText("yourFile.txt", 
                   DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
```